# How to add an animated GIF in Desktop Notification using Notification API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, notifications

I am creating a web app with a timer. Let's say every 30 seconds, it will fire a Desktop Notification using Notification API. I can do this smoothly, and also design it with images. But my problem is I want to add an animated GIF as Image on my notification. But when I add the image link, it only appears as a fixed (not moving or animating) image.

```
var notification = new Notification("Any Text will do",{
    icon: 'some-icon.jpg',
    body: 'Hello!',
    image: 'some-animated-pic.gif'
});
```

Thanks in advance and happy coding! ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: Unfortunately, animated images are not *currently* usable with the Notifications API, and are usually converted to a single frame grab, except for on IOS 10+. Sorry.

---

**Longer answer**, and evidence used to back up answer:

Likely because it is relatively new, the documentation and specifications for the Notifications API is rather weak. For example, this is basically all that the [WHATWG standard](https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/#image-resource) (Note: W3C standard is not up to date with WHATWG) says about image resources:

> An **image resource** is a picture shown as part of the content of the notification, and should be displayed with higher visual priority than the icon resource and badge resource, though it may be displayed in fewer circumstances.

Furthermore, at the moment, the `image` attribute is not even supported on many modern browser, including Firefox. [MDN compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification/image#Browser_compatibility).

The documentation for how each browser vendor (e.g. Chrome vs Firefox) implements this standard is even worse, likely because it is still labeled "experimental" and so nothing is really set in stone yet. For example, although Firefox does not accept use the `image` property yet, it will accept and show the full animation of a GIF passed as the `icon` property.

By manually testing in Chrome ([tool](https://tests.peter.sh/notification-generator/)), I was able to get the same results as what you stated; that it will accept an animated GIF as the `image` property, but only show a single frame from it. I can't find a single Chrome documentation that speaks to this being true, or why it is so.  However, poking around in the actual Chromium source code, I was able to find [clear evidence](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/modules/notifications/notification_image_loader.cc) that they are currently passing around Bitmaps and forcing single frames as output for images used with notifications.

IOS is the only exclusion here, as they introduced "Rich Media Push Notifications" with IOS 10, which supports animated GIFs, among other features. [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationattachment), [article about announcement](https://hackernoon.com/whats-new-in-ios-10-rich-notification-1350f267fe57).

Further links that back up my assertions here:

- [WonderPush](https://docs.wonderpush.com/docs/rich-media) (notes only iOS 10+ supports animating GIFs)
- OneSignal

  - [Big Picture on Android (warns GIF will be frozen on first frame)](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-customizations#section-big-picture)
  - [Web Push Notifications - Images (states Chrome does not support animations)](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-notification-icons#section-image)

Comment: Seems legit. Thanks, @Joshua T for the answer. Maybe I just make a workaround with only a single picture. But may I ask, how about the notifications by Slack. For example, a slack member will post a GIF, I can see the image animating on my notification. Is it because it's not created using Notifications API/ not created in HTML-JS? Thanks by the way! ^_^

Comment: Do you have Slack installed as a dedicated app instead of using it in the browser? Many operating systems have their own OS-specific notification frameworks set up, which, yes, Slack will use instead of the web notification API, if it is installed as an app. For example, on Windows, it can use the [Toast Notifications Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts).

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Thanks for the clarification! ^_^